# Members array not populating the chat ID

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am creating a website that enables users to chat using their native language. It uses firebase extension to translate the chats in real time.

I have integrated everything, we have created a members array that takes in the chat ID, and should display all the recent chats, but the members array isn't getting populated and the length is remaining '0'.

Following is the code.

For getting the members query from Firebase:

```
import {db} from "@/firebase";
import {
    DocumentData,
    FirestoreDataConverter,
    QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    SnapshotOptions,
    collection,
    collectionGroup,
    doc,
    query,
    where,

} from "firebase/firestore";

export interface  ChatMembers {
    userId: string;
    email: string;
    timestamp: Date | null;
    isAdmin: boolean;
    chatId: string;
    image: string;

}

const chatMembersConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<ChatMembers>={
    toFirestore: function (member: ChatMembers): DocumentData{
        return {
            userId: member.userId,
            email:  member.email,
            timestamp: member.timestamp,
            isAdmin: !!member.isAdmin,
            chatId: member.chatId,
            image: member.image,
        };
    },
    fromFirestore: function(
        snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot,
        options: SnapshotOptions
    ): ChatMembers {
        const data = snapshot.data(options);

        return {
            userId: snapshot.id,
            email: data.email,
            timestamp:data.timestamp,
            isAdmin:data.isAdmin,
            chatId: data.chatId,
            image:data.image,
        };

       
    },
};
export const addChatRef =(chatId: string, userId: string) =>
 doc(db, "chats",chatId,"members",userId).withConverter(chatMembersConverter 
 );



 export const chatMembersRef =(chatId:string)=>
 collection(db,"chats",chatId,"members").withConverter(
    chatMembersConverter
 );

 export const chatMemberAdminRef=(chatId:string)=>
 query(
    collection(db,"chats",chatId,"members"),
    where("isAdmin","==",true)
 ).withConverter(chatMembersConverter);

export const chatMembersCollectionGroupRef=(userId:string)=>
 query(
    collection(db,"members"),
    where("userId","==",userId)
 ).withConverter(chatMembersConverter);
```

The ChatListRows - that is responsible for querying the members and displaying the chats

```
"use client";

import { ChatMembers, chatMembersCollectionGroupRef } from "@/lib/converters/ChatMembers";
import { MessageSquare } from "lucide-react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import CreateChatButton from "./CreateChatButton";
import ChatListRow from "./ChatListRow";

function ChatListRows({initialChats}:{initialChats : ChatMembers[] }) {

  const { data: session } = useSession();
  

  const [ members, loading, error]= useCollectionData<ChatMembers>(
    session && chatMembersCollectionGroupRef(session?.user.id!),
    {
      initialValue: initialChats,
    }
  );
  

  if(members?.length === 0)
  return (
   <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center pt-40 space-y-2">
    <MessageSquare className="h-10 w-10"/>
    <h1 className="text-5xl font-extralight">Welcome!</h1>
    <h2 className="pb-10">
      Create your first chat.
    </h2>
    <CreateChatButton isLarge/>

   </div>

    );

 return (
  <div className="">
    {members?.map((member,i)=>(
      <ChatListRow key={member.chatId} chatId={member.chatId}/>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
  
}
;
export default ChatListRows;
```

I have console logged the members arrays and it still shows '0'

I have updated the firebase rules , but the error still exist

The error , that is the members array is not being updated , the error can be seen on the terminal , on the right hand side , in the image:

[image]

Comment: "I have console logged the members arrays and it still shows '0'". Instead of saying that in text, edit your question to show the code - and its output. That way we're all looking at the same thing. --- In general, I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [building a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) as following the guidance in there increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: I have added the image , sir